# App Crashing with libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_lane_resume

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, libdispatch

I got the logs from Firebase Crashlytics, my app is crashing but doesn't know where it is crashing. As crash logs are also not mentioning any specific line where the app is crashing. Please suggest if anybody else face such type of problem ever.

crash_info_entry_0

BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Over-resume of an object

crash_info_entry_1

CoreUI: deallocating _CUIInternalLinkRendition 44703 /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreGlyphs.bundle/Assets.car

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001a64eba34

```
**Stack trace**

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a64eba34 _dispatch_lane_resume + 700
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a64e5fd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a64e8758 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 408
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a64f8f18 _dispatch_source_invoke2 + 892
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a64f88c4 _dispatch_source_invoke + 428
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a64f1bb8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 696
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1a67bbcc8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1a67b6a24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1980
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1a67b5f40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
9  GraphicsServices               0x1b0a46534 GSEventRunModal + 108
10 UIKitCore                      0x1aa941580 UIApplicationMain + 1940
11 Big Idea Maths                 0x1005ffa10 main + 14 (main.m:14)
12 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a6634e18 start + 4
```

Comment: Could this article help? https://medium.com/over-engineering/a-background-repeating-timer-in-swift-412cecfd2ef9 - I had a similar crash, which was caused by resuming a background task that had already been resumed.

Comment: Hi @Tritonal what problem you were facing?

Comment: Can't remember exactly anymore, but I had a background task which I resumed/paused when needed, and when the app tried resuming a task which was already unpaused, the error was "over-resume of an object", like the one you have.

Comment: @Tritonal, we already implemented what link you provided. Still facing crash.